# Bозможно ли написать число используя чистый CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.entrance {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 550px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 3%, #4fc3f7, #ab5ca4 49%, #ff512f);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
}
.firstlayer {
  width: 15.9px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.secondlayer {
  width: 66.6px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.thirdlayer {
  
    width: 71.4px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="entrance">
  <div class="firstlayer"></div>
  <div class="secondlayer"></div>
  <div class="thirdlayer"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно написать эти числa на  CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.one:before,
.two:before,
.three:before {
  content: "1";
  display: block;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align-center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px
}

.two:before {
  content: "2";
}

.three:before {
  content: "3";
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое и кстати хороший никне́йм